# WordPress multi-site: How do I create the home page, the root URL?

Tags: multisite

I have a WordPress installation running since ages ago at mydomain.com. It's mostly administered by someone else, so I haven't really had to understand the inner workings of WordPress—I can create and edit content, but I don't mess around in the code.

Today I created a new site using the multi-site features, located at mydomain.com/project/. Everything went well—the site was created, I could set up the theme etc, but when I try to create the home page (i.e. simply mydomain.com/project), I can't get the URL right. No matter how I try, I'm not allowed to create a page with an empty slug, so all pages I create get something like mydomain.com/project/some-slug instead.

How do I create a page with the URL mydomain.com/project in this site?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can set your homepage in Wordpress by creating your page (the slug doesn't matter) and then going into `Settings` > `Reading` and selecting the page in `Front page displays` > `Front Page` setting.